# What does it mean when と is at the end of a noun list

Tags: particle-と

似てるよ、ユーマくんと初めて出会って時と。

I'm slightly confused at how と is used at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think it is supposed to be　**出会った**時, not 出会って.

Second, it will be easier to understand if you invert the sentence:

> ユーマくんと初めて出会った時**と**似てるよ。
>
> It's similar **to** that time when I first met Yuuma.